# Creating variables/automation in Microsoft Word

Tags: automation, ms-word

I write a lot of proposals in MS Word and we use a template that we go in and change out specific values, i.e. Client Name (used multiple times throughout document), URL, Price, Page count, etc... Sometimes these variables get overlooked or missed. I wanted to know is there a way to just type the Client name once and have it update throughout the page. Also is it possible to edit these values in a separate document and link the proposal template to generate a modified proposal each time?

I'd like to know if all this is possible within just Word and not using VB scripts or anything like that.

Comment: You can do it with a VBA macro, but unfortunately I haven't seen any easy way to do this without code.

Answer (score 0):

[Mail merge](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294683)?

Or maybe a [template/form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-forms-that-users-complete-in-word-HA010030746.aspx) would be better for you.